# Remote debugging an EC2 Windows Tomcat application with Eclipse produces "Operation timed out" errors

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, amazon-ec2, timeout

**Where I'm at:**

I'm trying to remote debug a Java application hosted on a Windows instance in AWS using Eclipse. All configuration permutations I've tried produce a "Failed to connect to remote VM: Operation timed out" error in the Eclipse remote debugger.

**What I'm using:**

Server: Windows Server 2019 Datacenter in an AWS EC2 m5a.large instance

Running: Apache Tomcat 9.0.75 Server, Daemon 1.3.3.0, Oracle Java 1.8.0_291-b10

Client: MacOS 12.6.3, Eclipse 2023-06

**What I've Tried:**

I've confirmed with `nmap` that the port I'm shooting for (8085, as well as previous attempts using 8000) is open in Windows Firewall and unblocked by AWS security groups. Packets for port 8085 show in Windows Firewall logs and are not being dropped. Hopefully we can set that aside and assume the problem is my Tomcat/Eclipse config.

In the Daemon/GUI I currently have

```
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8085,server=y,suspend=n
```

set under the **Java** tab **at the top** of the Java options box **before -D options**. The latter details are often stressed in other posts. I have also tried

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8085,server=y,suspend=n
```

since that is sometimes suggested for Java versions above 5 – no avail. I tried `.bat`-based approaches although I'm pretty sure this is incompatible with a Tomcat service-based config e.g.:

```
set JPDA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8085,server=y,suspend=n
```

in `setenv.bat` or `catalina.bat`. I'd think one would want it to read `address=*:8085`, but this prevents Tomcat from starting. Logs provide nothing useful in this regard – `stdout initializing` and `exit code 0` or something to that effect.

I've seen many mentions of setting CATALINA_OPTS/JPDA_OPTS/JPDA_ADDRESS/etc. but again, I don't believe this pertains to service configs. Nevertheless, I've tried setting these in Windows Environment Variables and `setenv.bat` to no effect.

I tried adding `jpda` before `start` in the "Arguments" box of the "Startup" tab, but that was more of a crapshoot than anything. Predictably, it didn't work.

In Eclipse, I've confirmed 10x that I have the correct host and port in my Remote Java Application debug config. I'm using Socket Attach connection type and "Source" seems to contain the correct files. The internal browser within Eclipse is connected to the internet, so I assume everything's playing nice with my proxy. I've also increased the Preferences -> Java -> Debug -> debug & launch timeouts to 600000 and 1200000ms, respectively.

Of course, I've restarted the server, Eclipse, etc.

**What I feel:**

I'm at a complete loss here. Thank you for any help – please save me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.